# Easy way converting string to int?

Tags: c++, string, converters

How can i convert a string of number (and i mean string not char ,because the atoi function works for char ,and didn't work for string for me) to an integer .
I tried this but it didn't work :

```
int main(){
int P,W;
string ST1 , ST2;
getline(cin,ST1,' ');
getline(cin,ST2);
P = std::atoi(ST1);
W = std::atoi(ST1);
return 0 ;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call any function taking a `const char *` with a `string` using `.c_str()`:

```
P = std::atoi(ST1.c_str());
```

Comment: Yes, but why do that when there's `std::stoi`?

Comment: @us2012: This technique is generally useful for calling *any* function that takes `const char *`, not merely for converting strings to integer. Also, `std::stoi` is C++11 (and later) only.